# React component consuming custom hook does not detect hook's state update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom hook `useReservation`

```
export default function useReservation() {
  const [reservation, setReservation] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    update()
  }, [])

  const update = () => {
    api(ApiRequestType.GET_RESERVATION, { token })
      .then((res) => {
        setReservation(res.data)
      })
  }

  return { reservation, update }
}
```

and my goal is to use `useReservation` on two components: `ProjectList` and `ProjectListItem`

```
export default function ProjectList() {
  const { reservation } = useReservation()
  return (
    <>
      reservation.map(r => (
        <ProjectListItem reservation={r}/>
      ))
    </>
  )
}
```

```
export default function ProjectListItem() {
  const { update } = useReservation()
  return (
    ...
    <button onClick={update}>
    ...   
  )
}
```

My issue is when I update from `ProjectListItem`, the function in the hook gets called, the state in hook is updated, but `ProjectList` does not detect the changes. How do I fix it (if it is fixable)?

p.s. don't mind the code. I abstracted the code for better readability, everything is working except this part.

Comment: `setState()` is for LOCAL state. You call `useReservation()` in two separate components then you will have TWO different local states (so to speak). Update one and the other won't be affected. Pull it up and expose it using React context (for example...). Note: `ProjectListItem` in `ProjectList` should have a `key`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I see. Thank you so much that clears everything.

Comment: As @AdrianoRepetti said it is correct. For your requirement I would suggest try to use [this](https://swr.vercel.app) and see if it's help you

Comment: thank you @ShubhamVerma. I use axios and actually use redux. Not an issue, just curious on why this happens.